# How to fix memory access violation with OpenGL glViewport?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, imgui

I am trying to build an application in C++ with ImGUI, OpenGL and GLFW.

However, when i try to run my program, i get a white screen that then crashes and gives me an error code of -1073741819.

Here is my Class for creating a window, alot of the stuff i copied from the ImGUI opengl3 example:

```
#include <imgui_impl_glfw.h>
#include <imgui_impl_opengl3.h>
#include <imgui_internal.h>
#include "imgui.h"
#include "AppWindow.h"

static void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GLFW Error %d: %s\n", error, description);
}

AppWindow::AppWindow(const char* title, int width, int height)
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        return ;

    // Decide GL+GLSL versions
#if defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_ES2)
    // GL ES 2.0 + GLSL 100
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 100";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    // GL 3.0 + GLSL 130
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif

    // Create window with graphics context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
        return ;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1); // Enable vsync

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;     // Enable Keyboard Controls
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;      // Enable Gamepad Controls
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable;         // Enable Docking
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable;       // Enable Multi-Viewport / Platform Windows
    //io.ConfigViewportsNoAutoMerge = true;
    //io.ConfigViewportsNoTaskBarIcon = true;

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
    //ImGui::StyleColorsLight();

    // When viewports are enabled we tweak WindowRounding/WindowBg so platform windows can look identical to regular ones.
    ImGuiStyle& style = ImGui::GetStyle();
    if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
    {
        style.WindowRounding = 0.0f;
        style.Colors[ImGuiCol_WindowBg].w = 1.0f;
    }

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(glsl_version);

    // Our state
    bool show_demo_window = true;
    bool show_another_window = false;


}

AppWindow::~AppWindow()
{

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    EMSCRIPTEN_MAINLOOP_END;
#endif

    // Cleanup
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return;
}



void AppWindow::setUpdateFunction(void (*function)())
{
    updateFunction = function;
}

void AppWindow::update()
{
    if (updateFunction != nullptr)
        updateFunction();
}

void AppWindow::run()
{
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    // For an Emscripten build we are disabling file-system access, so let's not attempt to do a fopen() of the imgui.ini file.
    // You may manually call LoadIniSettingsFromMemory() to load settings from your own storage.
    io.IniFilename = nullptr;
    EMSCRIPTEN_MAINLOOP_BEGIN
#else
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
#endif
    {
        // Poll and handle events (inputs, window resize, etc.)
        // You can read the io.WantCaptureMouse, io.WantCaptureKeyboard flags to tell if dear imgui wants to use your inputs.
        // - When io.WantCaptureMouse is true, do not dispatch mouse input data to your main application, or clear/overwrite your copy of the mouse data.
        // - When io.WantCaptureKeyboard is true, do not dispatch keyboard input data to your main application, or clear/overwrite your copy of the keyboard data.
        // Generally you may always pass all inputs to dear imgui, and hide them from your application based on those two flags.
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        update();

        // Rendering
        ImGui::Render();
        int display_w, display_h;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &display_w, &display_h);
        glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        // Update and Render additional Platform Windows
        // (Platform functions may change the current OpenGL context, so we save/restore it to make it easier to paste this code elsewhere.
        //  For this specific demo app we could also call glfwMakeContextCurrent(window) directly)
        if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
        {
            GLFWwindow* backup_current_context = glfwGetCurrentContext();
            ImGui::UpdatePlatformWindows();
            ImGui::RenderPlatformWindowsDefault();
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(backup_current_context);
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }


}

void AppWindow::addMouseCallBack(GLFWmousebuttonfun action)
{
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, action);
}

void AppWindow::addKeyCallBack(GLFWkeyfun action)
{
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, action);
}
```

my main method:

```
int main(int ,  char**) {
AppWindow window("My app", 1280, 720);


window.run();

return 0;
```

}

AppWindow.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "imgui.h"

class AppWindow
{
public:
    ImVec4 BgColour = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);
    ImGuiIO io;
    GLFWwindow* window;
    void (*updateFunction)() = nullptr;

    AppWindow(const char* title, int width, int height);
    ~AppWindow();


    void setUpdateFunction(void (*updateFunction)());

    void update();

    void run();

    void addMouseCallBack(GLFWmousebuttonfun action);

    void addKeyCallBack(GLFWkeyfun action);
```

here is an image of my folder structure:
[my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zonFu.png)

here is the imgui files I copied over:
[imgui files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6n5s.png)

my include directory contains:
Desktop\ImgGUIApps\LearningImGUI\ImGUIwithOpenGL\imguiDependencies
Desktop\ImgGUIApps\LearningImGUI\ImGUIwithOpenGL\Libraries\include

my library directory:
Desktop\ImgGUIApps\LearningImGUI\ImGUIwithOpenGL\Libraries\lib

additonal dependencies:
glfw3.lib

I figured out that this occurs due to a memory access violation in this portion of code as it runs:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);
glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

commenting that out just gives me a non-crashing black screen.

I suspect that this may be due to me installing opengl and glfw and imgui incorrectly.

I also don't think that it is because my window variable is being freed, as i declared it in the class declaration.

Comment: `glViewport` seems to be the very first OpenGL instruction.

Comment: The exit code -1073741819 in hex is 0xC0000005. If you look up this code in Microsoft's documentation (NTSTATUS Values) you will see that it indicates that your program was terminated due to an access violation. This error can occur for a variety of reasons, including de-referencing a `nullptr` pointer or referencing an invalid address.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? My guess would be something with "exception while **execution** location ...". In that case, the OpenGL methods aren't loaded.

Comment: How do you load or access the OpenGL functions?

Comment: the error i got was simply : " exited with code -1073741819."

Comment: @NicolBolas I am using glad to load opengl functions. I put glad.h in an include directory and glad.c in the src folder. I used the gl specification of glad at version 4.6.

Comment: Where do you call `gladLoadGL` or [`gladLoadGLLoader`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#glad_(Multi-Language_GL/GLES/EGL/GLX/WGL_Loader-Generator))?

Comment: @G.M. I didn't it seems. I just found out that I needed to do that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i had to simply write:

```
gladLoadGL();
```

after

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

I don't remember seeing it in tutorials, or maybe I wasn't paying attention. Anyhow, thanks to @G.M. for making the solution clear to me.